# SQL Server stored procedure expects parameter even though the parameter is provided

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

In C# app I am trying to use a stored procedure but came accross a strange error.

Here is table definition:

```
create table bed_allotment
(
    bill_id bigint,
    bed_category varchar(50),
    for_days int
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure AddBed
(
    @bill_id bigint,
    @bed_category varchar(50),
    @for_days int
)
as
begin
    insert into bed_allotment 
    values (@bill_id, @bed_category, @for_days)
end
```

Code on button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand AddBedCommand = new SqlCommand("AddBed", con);

    AddBedCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bill_id", 1330);
    AddBedCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bed_category", "ICCU");
    AddBedCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@for_days", 6);

    con.Open();
    AddBedCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

When I execute this, error occurs. It says

> SQL procedure expects parameter '@bill_id' which was not provided

What's the mistake? Any suggestions will be a great help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [`AddBedCommand.CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) to [`CommandType.StoredProcedure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx) so that the request is an [RPC request](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/).

Comment: Oh man, I am wondering myself how can i forgot to set command type...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AddBedCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
AddBedCommand.Parameters.Add("@bill_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1330;
AddBedCommand.Parameters.Add("@bed_category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ICCU";
AddBedCommand.Parameters.Add("@for_days", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 6;
```