# Stored procedure expects parameter though parameter is provided

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

I am using VS 2015 and SQL Server 2016.

In my C# code, I am assigning the parameters which my stored procedure expects, but am getting an error as my stored procedure is expecting a parameter.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDDeleteTAR]
    @TARKey int
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE technical_assistance_requests  
    WHERE request_id = @TARKey
END
```

My C# code:

```
Label id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("REQUEST_ID");
var x = id.Text;
int rid = Convert.ToInt32(x);

string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connectionString").ToString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SDDeleteTAR", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestID", rid); 

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> Procedure or function 'SDDeleteTAR' expects parameter '@TARKey', which was not supplied.

I am passing the required parameters and executing my command type as `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, and am not able to resolve this.

I also checked the same issue in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395369/sql-server-stored-procedure-expects-parameter-even-though-the-parameter-is-provi) but the submitter is missing the command type declaration.

Any help is appreciated, in pointing out where I am going wrong.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thanks, will check it out, but VS suggested to use this instead of .Add saying that it was deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change `@RequestID` to `@TARKey`. Because your stored procedure expects a parameter with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely execute a stored procedure without directly specifying the names, by using [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx). This will retrieve the parameters from the server and create the SQLParameter collection for you.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SDDeleteTAR", con);
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = rid;
```

Comment: Thanks for this method, will try it out.